# In angular simple app, I have to show common header to all pages after login, but common header is not visible to user details page

Tags: php, angular, angular-material

**In angular simple app, I have to show common header to all pages after login,  but common header is not visible to user details page**

**I want to make common header visible to user details page also, which is not going to happen.**

```
-myapp
  -src
   -layout
    -common
      -header
       header.component.css
       header.component.html
       header.component.spec.ts
       header.component.ts
    -dashboard
     dashboard-routing.module.ts
     dashboard.component.css
     dashboard.component.html
     dashboard.component.spec.ts
     dashboard.module.ts
     dashboard.component.ts
     - userdetails
       userdetails-routing.module.ts
       userdetails.component.css
       userdetails.component.html
       userdetails.component.spec.ts
       userdetails.module.ts
       userdetails.component.ts
   layout-routing.module.ts
   layout.component.css
   layout.component.html
   layout.component.spec.ts
   layout.module.ts
   layout.component.ts
 -login
 -services
 app-routing.module.ts
 app.component.css
 app.component.html
 app.component.spec.ts
 app.module.ts
 app.component.ts
```

**layout & dashboard components module & routing files are lazy files**

**app.modules.ts:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

import { LayoutModule } from './layout/layout.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,    
    LayoutModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**layout.modules.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { LayoutRoutingModule } from './layout-routing.module';
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout.component';
import { DashboardModule } from './dashboard/dashboard.module';
import { HeaderComponent } from './common/header/header.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LayoutComponent,
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    LayoutRoutingModule,
    DashboardModule
  ],
  exports: [HeaderComponent]
})
export class LayoutModule { }
```

**dashbard.modules.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { DashboardRoutingModule } from './dashboard-routing.module';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component'

import { UserdetailsModule } from './userdetails/userdetails.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [DashboardComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DashboardRoutingModule,
    UserdetailsModule
  ],
  exports: [DashboardComponent]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**layout.component.html:**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**dashboard.component.html:**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
..
..
```

**app-routing.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './layout/dashboard/dashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: LoginComponent },  
  { path: 'layout', loadChildren: './layout/layout.module#LayoutModule'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**layout-routing.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' }
    ]
  }  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LayoutRoutingModule { }
```

**dashboard-routing.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { UserdetailsComponent } from './userdetails/userdetails.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {path: "user-details/:id", loadChildren: './userdetails/userdetails.module#UserdetailsModule'}
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

**Please suggest me changes to show that common header on user-details page also**..

Comment: Can you please add your code to the question? No one wants to go back and forward between multiple screenshots.

Comment: @Steve edited.. please check it once now

Answer (score 0):

you defined HeaderComponent inside LayoutModule and using it inside AppModule so you must export it so AppModule could see it, refactor like this

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent,
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    LayoutRoutingModule
  ],
  exports:[HeaderComponent] //here it will export header component
})
export class LayoutModule { }
```

Comment: yes I have also added that.. but not showing that header on user-details page.. I edited question.. please help me solve this

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is just a router configuration issue. I have made some changes to your code . Please Refer : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rtzy77

I have not added routing module but have created the routes in the module itself .

The only Change that i have done is removal of `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` from `dashboard.component.ts` .

You don't need a 3rd router outlet .

**EDIT 1** : Even after adding the 3rd route , i have covered your use case. . The example should work . Please refer to the stackblitz example

Open : https://angular-ivy-rtzy77.stackblitz.io/layout/dashboard/user for the required header and user component

**EDIT 2** : 
Also ,instead Of using multiple nesting , you can make changes to your `layout-routing.module` in the following way keeping the user module inside layout module rather than dashboard module and then remove `router-outlet` from `dashboard.component` .

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: LayoutComponent,
        children: [
      { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },
{path: "user-details/:id", loadChildren: './userdetails/userdetails.module#UserdetailsModule'}
    ]
  }  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LayoutRoutingModule { }
```

And then in dashboard.component.html , remove `router-outlet` . With just 2 `router-outlet` you can meet your requirements .

Comment: its going to work, but is it proper way if we declare user-details routing directly in layout-routing instead of dashboard.. is it standard way in parent child relation.. please let me know

Comment: and suppose if there are more than one urls of user-details module then how we are going to mention in layout-routing

Comment: userdetails module is inside dashboard module

Comment: @HemantP , the example i created using stackblitz is basically using the same code . If there is no parent and child relationship between dashboard and user module then you can remove the router outlet in dashboard and use the user module in layout module . Else the example i created should work fine .